# Access to data in different lifecycles

Tags: reactjs

I'm integrating my react app with `branch.io` so I can retrieve some data when a user opens a custom link. The documentation requires me to put in a script in `index.html` but I want to be able to access that data in my components (e.g. App.jsx). I want to store that data in localStorage and redux and then redirect the user to the correct page.

What is an appropriate way of getting the data inside my components rather than writing logic in the `index.html`? Also, what would be a good place/lifecycle hook to check if there's any data that I stored in localStorage?

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode autoAppIndex banner closeBanner closeJourney creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setBranchViewData setIdentity track validateCode trackCommerceEvent logEvent disableTracking getBrowserFingerprintId crossPlatformIds lastAttributedTouchData".split(" "), 0);

    let branchKeyTest = 'key_test_ABCD123'

    branch.init(branchKeyTest, function(err, data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 1))
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Just an idea, but can you put these code on componentDidMount in App.jsx? Any valid js code in index.html should be valid in React as well.

Comment: When I put the code to `componentDidMount`, I'm noticing that there are multiple renders and it "skips" the function to initialize the branch data. Any idea how I can ensure that componentDidMount is fully executed before the next render?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. componentDidMount is not a blocking function. Meaning that react will not wait for the function to complete before rendering. You might need to have a boolean state isLoaded. If isLoaded is false, render() return null. After the init is completed, use setState to set isLoaded to true